# How does the syntax look like to create and test a vector? [level: newbie]

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I'm studying Java a bit and want to create a vector class to understand exceptions and arrays. In my case I go with double arrays first.

I implemented two constructors for my class. One for the length and one for the array.

The variable length contains the length of the vector.

Get() and set() were implemented to read or change the values.

Minimum(), maximum() and average() were implemented to get the wanted  values of the array.

toString() should print the vector as a string.

My code so far

```
public class MyVector {

    //lenght of the vector
    public final int l;

    //array representing the vector
    private double[] arr;


    // Constructs vector.
    public MyVector(int l) {
        this.l = l;
        arr = new double[l];
    }

    // Constructs  vector from  existing array
    public MyVector(double[] array) {
        l = array.length;

        // copy]
        arr = new double[l];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            arr[i] = array[i];
    }


    //gets value at the given index.
    public double get(int index) {
        return arr[index];

    }

    // Sets  value at the given index.
    public double set(int index, double value) {

    }


    // Returns the minimal value in the vector.
    public double minimum() {
        double minimum = get(0);

        for (int i=1; i<arr.l; i++)
            if (get(i)<minimum)
                minimum = get(i);

        return minimum;    }

    // Returns the maximal value in the vector.
    public double maximum() {
        double maximum = get(0);

        for (int i=1; i<arr.l; i++)
            if (get(i)>maximum)
                maximum = get(i);

        return maximum;    }

    // the average of all values in the vector
    public double average() {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<arr.l; i++)
            sum += get(i);  
        return sum/arr.l;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[arr=" + arr.l
                + " min=" + min()
                + " max=" + maximum()
                + " avg=" + average();
    }
}
```

First of all I want to test some vectors. I guess I need testerclass for my vector with `public static void main(String[] args) { }` and two testermethods. One to test the class and one to test the methods of the class. How would the syntax look like to create and test a vector?

I appreciate any feedback to my myvector class as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an instance of `MyVector`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I just thought that I could create a vector array, but I do not understand how it works. Is there something like Vector[] v;
     v = new Vector[5];
     v[0] = new Vector(2);
     v[1] = new Vector(5);
     v[2] = new Vector(6);
     v[3] = new Vector(4);
     v[4] = new Vector(9); ?  I'm interested in finding the highest value  of the array, and the lowest value as well as the average the values.

Comment: Lookup https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html, JUnit, and Java Collections in general.

Comment: You don't need to store the array length separately. In Java you can simply do arr.length to obtain it, as you also do in some places in this code

Comment: Hm..I just want to test my methods. Here is an example of what the results shoud look like: . I want a vector with following values: 2.0, 5.0, 6.0 , 4.0 and 8.0. The minium value of the vector array would be 2.0, the max would be 8.0 and the avg would be 5.0. How can i create that array and print the tested results of the methods?

Answer (score 1):

The statements you wrote in your comments responding to Mureinik would work but it's not clear what they'd get you, other than an array of vectors of varying lengths.

Re the goal you stated in your question, you could get started with testing in a fairly rudimentary way by simply creating a test class with a bunch of test methods and a `main` method that runs them all. E.g. one might be something like:

```
public boolean testAverage(Vector v, double expected) {
  double computed = v.average();
  boolean passed = expected == computed;
  if (!passed) {
    System.err.printf("Incorrect average for %s; expected %f, got %f\n",
      v, expected, computed);
  }
  return passed;
}
```

At some point you'll want to learn about JUnit, for which there are numerous tutorials that you'll find via searching. It's a whole framework for writing tests for your Java classes. But for a self-professed newbie it's probably a lot to take on until you've become more comfortable with the language. Kudos for being motivated to write tests early in your learning curve.

Comment: Hi, maybe I should be more specific. I want a vector with following values: 2.0, 5.0, 6.0 , 4.0 and 8.0. The minium value of the vector array would be 2.0, the max would be 8.0 and the avg would be 5.0. I know that this is not the common use of a vector, but I want to learn about arrays. After my vector class is working I thought about implementing a matrix class. Thanks for your answer and your cheering up.